# Should alerts cover the navbar? App content?

Tags: alerts

Should alerts cover the navbar? App content?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuxyv1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Argument for why they should cover things: The alert should take your attention away from everything else, and it's going to be dismissed soon anyway.

Argument for why they shouldn't cover things: Because you should let the user continue what they're doing without being interrupted, and let them view the alert when they're ready.

Comment: In this specific example I'd put the alert over the title, because that is static content. You'd still let them navigate and the rest of the page without changing the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Well in your example the notification is a feedback for the user that his action was successful or an indicator that it wasn't.

Thats why i believe your not really interrupting him in the first place since he just finished an action and will most likely see the notification before starting his next action.

Notifications don't have to cover the whole navbar tho, there are solutions like toaster notifications for a reason, the user gets informed in a more subtle way without getting interrupted/irritated to much, for example:
http://carlosroso.com/notyf/

If you want to go one step further you can provide the user with the ability to configure the notification settings with options like: don't show notifications, position of the notification etc.

Comment: In this specific example they might just have done finished their task, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdWdLv.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I believe that you don't have to take up the whole navbar for showing the notification. It would be better to show the notification as an alert that should be dismissed by the user.